# Arc: Setting references to nil, for multiple buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

When displaying an item such as a button in a ViewController, I declare it in the header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *startButton;
```

Synthesize it in the implementation file:

```
@synthesize startButton;
```

Initiate it in the implementation file:

```
startButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
```

And set the reference to nil in viewDidUnload:

```
[self setStartButton:nil];
```

However, **what if I have 60 listed items** (in a UIScrollView) which are created dynamically in a loop, in viewDidLoad (fed from Core Data)?
(Not using TableView, because the items are quite complicated and interactive.)

Should I declare the items anywhere first? **Should I set them to nil anywhere?** (Or should I just keep my fingers crossed and pray to the Arc?)

Some guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what you mean by item?is it startButton?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your view controller have properties or instance variables that point to each of those 60 items?

**Yes:** Then set those ivars or properties to nil in your `-viewDidUnload`.

**No:** Then there's nothing to worry about.

ARC changes *what you do* to manage memory, but it doesn't change the basic philosophy, which is that every object should take care of its own references to other objects but not worry about anybody else's.

In this case, the view that contains all those items will have strong references to the items (via it's array of subviews). When the view controller releases its view, that view will then be deallocated and release all its subviews in the process. So all those items will be taken care of. If you did have strong references to any of those items, those references will prevent the referenced objects from being deallocated -- setting the references to nil will avoid that.

Comment: I think that answers my question very well, and makes Arc clearer to me too. Thanks very much for your answer Caleb!

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating these views on the fly and adding them as subviews of the scrollView, then you don't need to do anything else.

When the scrollView is released during `-viewDidUnload`, it will properly clean up all its subviews.

---

**Update**

Think of it this way. In a normal view setup on a storyboard, you don't need have a property for every view, only the views your controller interacts with. This is basically the same thing. You have a bunch of views that are embedded into a superview. If the controller doesn't interact with them, then you don't need to worry about them.

Comment: Are you sure, Jeffery? This would be perfect if so!

Comment: Added an analogy to views on a storyboard.

Comment: Thanks very much Jeffery. Your and answer, along with Caleb's, is very useful. Sorry I could not give you both a green tick!

Answer (score 0):

no. :)

**you definitely set the all pointer to** `nil` **what are not necessary anymore** when you are using the `ARC`.

the `ARC` will release the memory of the current object when there is no more `strong` pointer who tries to keep alive the object. if you don't set them to `nil` the `ARC` thinks you are still using them and they will be in the memory and they will cause serious memory leak.

**UPDATE #1**

if you have any reference for the buttons this is the easiest way to do it, you don't need to do set to `nil` anything, because their `superview` class `retain` them and you should just remove from their `superview`.

```
for (UIView *_subView in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([_subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [_subView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

if you're storing their pointer any other place (in an `NSArray` for ex.) you must have to remove the pointers from them as well.

Comment: Thanks. So if I have about 60 items, how should I do this!?

Comment: They are created in viewDidLoad, using a UIView class, data from Core Data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply holex. Based on other answers, I think my items will be automatically removed, when the ScrollView is removed. But your code looks useful otherwise. Thanks.