# Can i reuse UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, reusability

I have UIView in my storyboard with outlet mynewView and i want it display with totally different content.  And do it many times.

My UIView contains many objects, i load it from internet. But every time i do

```
    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [view1 mynewView];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }

    //Let's try to remove all possible views..

    viewsToRemove = [self.view subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }

    //here i create mynewView
    mynewView = [self createnewRandomView];
    //And finally add the View we have created.

    [self.view addSubview:mynewView];
```

i monitor the memory consumption and i see it grows every time i add new UIView. Even when i remove all superviews. I guess they remain in memory.

Before i change the view i remove from superview all possible views, but they still stay in memory.

Xcode is set to use ARC so i can't release it.

Is there any good way to reuse a UIView?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view addSubview:mynewView];
```

Your newView was added as subview of self.view.
Your above code does not use for remove yourVewView in self.view.
Please try this code before adding new view:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view) {
   if([view isKindOfClass:[YourNewViewClassName class]])
   {
       [view removeFromSuperView];
       break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As you remove the subviews, set them to `nil` as you go, like so:

```
for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
   [v removeFromSuperview];
    v = nil;
}
```

For more information, see for example [Arc: Setting references to nil, for multiple buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542720/arc-setting-references-to-nil-for-multiple-buttons)

Comment: You should really read that linked article - note the "NO"-part and check your answer again.

Comment: I missed the fact that the original asker does not hold references to the subviews, sorry. What would be your answer then?